# How to keep duplicate properties in compiled CSS file when use LESS?

Tags: less

LESS code

```
.foo {
  background-size: 200px; //for old browsers
  background-size: cover;
}
```

CSS expected

```
.foo {
  background-size: 200px; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

but less.js remove the first `background-size` property in compiled CSS file.

Comment: Less (atleast as at v1.7.5) would not remove the first setting. Are you using any other options during compilation like compress etc? Even `--clean-css` doesn't seem to b removing it.

Comment: Only `--clean-css="--advanced"` will remove such properties (so I'm afraid if you use that you have to turn it off in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS already pointed out by @seven-phases-max `clean-css` removes these properties.

<strike>Notice that the `--advanced` has been set by default. You should use the `--skip-advanced` option to prevent your double properties from being removed.</strike>

According to https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css the `advanced` option has been set to false by default.

`lessc foo.less` outputs:

```
.foo {
  background-size: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

`lessc --clean-css foo.less` outputs:

```
.foo{background-size:200px;background-size:cover}
```

`lessc --clean-css="advanced" foo.less` outputs:

```
 .foo{background-size:cover}
```

Alternatively you could run `lessc -x foo.less` which also outputs:

```
.foo{background-size:200px;background-size:cover}
```