# Does LESS prevent duplicate styles?

Tags: less

If I define the following nested styles in LESS:

```
.nav-bar {
    .navbar-brand {
        background: #000;
    }
}

.nav-bar {
    .navbar-brand {
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

It results in:

```
.nav-bar .navbar-brand {
  background: #000;
}
.nav-bar .navbar-brand {
  background: #fff;
}
```

I was hoping that these might be detected as duplicates. So, the result would simply be:

```
.nav-bar .navbar-brand {
  background: #fff;
}
```

.. as the first style would be overwritten. I know that the web browser would treat it as such, whereby the second styles properties would overwrite the first. I'm more concerned about file size though. I was hoping that I could download LESS for Bootstrap, then in a custom LESS file, overwrite styles for that particular project. Is this feature available by the compiler?

Comment: Well written/formatted question.  No reason for this to be down-voted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css with the `advanced` option turned on.

Run `npm install less-plugin-clean-css` after that you can use `lessc file.less --clean-css="advanced"`.

With the above command:

```
.nav-bar {
    .navbar-brand {
        background: #000;
    }
}

.nav-bar {
    .navbar-brand {
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

compiles into:

```
.nav-bar .navbar-brand{background:#fff}
```

Also see: [How to keep duplicate properties in compiled CSS file when use LESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544448/how-to-keep-duplicate-properties-in-compiled-css-file-when-use-less/27612169)